# Sending child stdout to parent stdout

Tags: fork, pipe, parent-child

I am working on a simple application that takes the output from another one and writes it to a socket. 
Below is the code for the application that I am execvp'ing
this code is called simple App

```
    int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
   int count = 0;
   while(count < 5)
       //Attempt fork
        if((pid2 = fork()) < 0) //Failed to fork
        {
                printf("\n Failed to fork in Dump \n");
                exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid2 == 0) //Child Code
        {
                dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,pipefd[1]);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                if(execvp("../App/App", dumpParam) < 0) //execute the app; returns -1 if failed

                {
                        printf("\nFailed to execute App\n");
                        exit(1);
                }
        }
        else //Parent
        {
                close(pipefd[1]);
                memset(buff,'0',sizeof(buff));
                printf("here\n");
                while( (r = read(pipefd[0],buff,sizeof(buff))) >= 0)
                {
                        printf("\nSuccess in read r = %d\n",r);
                        printf("\nBuff = %s\n",buff);
                        memset(buff,'0',sizeof(buff));

                }
                printf("nowHere\n");
        }
        return pipefd[0];
```

so far when i run it, it prints out just a ton of 0's. if i set read > 0 then it doesn't run at all. Thoughts?

Comment: Your code doesn't even declare `pipefd`. Or call `pipe()`. Post something that compiles at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` is returning 0 (end of file) because the child end of the pipe is closed.

You've got the dup2 the wrong way round, it should be

```
dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)
```

also remove

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO)
```